# можете помочь расположить горизонтально эти div объекты

Tags: css

```html
<div class="article_1" align="left">
  <p>
    <h1 id="title_article_1">СХД HP MSA P2000 G3 Modular Smart Array и учётные данные по умолчанию.</h1>
  </p>
  <p>
    <h2 id="text_article_1">В конфигурации по умолчанию у контроллеров управления системы хранения данных HP MSA P2000 G3 имеется несколько встроенных учётных записей. Пароли этих учётных записей любой вменяемый администратор сменит при первой же настройке контроллеров управления.
      Однако, даже много лет проработав с подобной железкой, и предполагая, что в этой области нет никаких "белых пятен", в один прекрасный день можно открыть для себя совершенно удивительные и неизвестные ранее подробности, от которых на голове могут
      зашевелиться волосы.</h2>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="comments_1" align="right">
  <p><i><h2 id="author1" align="left" ; >Arthur Sharifov</h2></i></p>
  <p>
    <h2 id="tect_comment1" align="left">Блин, реально помогло, спасибо!</h2>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду, но кажется это то, что вам нужно

```css
     body {
        display: flex;
     }
     .article_1 {
        width: 70%;
     }
     .comments_1 {
        width: 30%;
     }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="article_1" align="left">
                <p><h1 id="title_article_1"  >СХД HP MSA P2000 G3 Modular 
                    Smart Array и учётные данные по умолчанию.</h1></p>
                <p><h2 id="text_article_1">В конфигурации по умолчанию у 
                    контроллеров управления системы хранения данных HP MSA 
                    P2000 G3 имеется несколько встроенных учётных записей. 
                    Пароли этих учётных записей любой вменяемый 
                    администратор сменит при первой же настройке 
                    контроллеров управления. Однако, даже много лет 
                    проработав с подобной железкой, и предполагая, что в этой области нет никаких "белых пятен", в один прекрасный день можно открыть для себя совершенно удивительные и неизвестные ранее подробности, от которых на голове могут зашевелиться волосы.</h2></p>
            </div>
            <div class="comments_1" align="right">
                <p><i><h2 id="author1" align="left" ; >Arthur Sharifov</h2></i></p>
                <p><h2 id="tect_comment1" align="left">Блин, реально помогло, спасибо!</h2></p>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```